# Android: Send notification FROM device TO computer

Tags: android, testing, adb

Our continuous integration environment runs a custom test framework from ADB on a Windows machine. The tests may pass or fail but how can we notify Windows in either case?

We must run on physical devices so the emulator is not an option.

I have toyed with the idea of writing a file to the device from the framework when it is finished and having something running on Windows  periodically poll the device for the file. I'm sure most would agree that's a bit ugly but I'm stumped on this one.

Any suggestions are welcome, P

Comment: Could you just set up a server that the device sends a notice to?

Comment: But where would the server live? Internet connectivity from the test device is not an option unfortunatley. Hosting some Servlet on the Windows machine is an option but how does the device communicate with it?

Comment: hmmm you starting test from adb.... then why dont you use adb logcat for returning test results ? you can write service (on windows) that reads logcat output and store result somewhere

Comment: I suppose I could pipe LogCat's output somewhere else and monitor it for communication from our application. Thank you, Selvin.